# Определить местоположение пользователя

Tags: геолокация, android

Доброго времени суток!  
А каким способом вы определяете местоположение пользователя?
После длительных мучений по поиску способов определения местоположения для "единоразового" использования я решил обратиться к Вам, уважаемые знатоки! Дело в том, что я поддерживаю проект уже продолжительное время, и способов определения местоположения было около трех.

- Первый способ был примерно такой, как 
     в этом [примере](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/) с перебором
     провайдеров, однако находились
     устройства, на которых это не
     работало, либо работало через раз.
- Второй способ был модификацией
     первого, но уже с использованием
     фонового потока, который при
     нахождении местоположения
     информировал об этом, способ оказался
     лучше первого не во все стороны, но
     искал местоположение лучше, т.е.
     заработало так где не работало. Но опять же нашлись девайсы где и этого оказалось недостаточно
- Вот третий способ казалось должен был
     быть стопроцентным, так как основан
     был на картах гугла, которые вроде бы
     должны определять местоположение
     всегда, когда это возможно.
     Создавался экземпляр MapView, которая
     никогда не показывалась, создавался
     MyLocationOverlay для показа
     пользователя и он то нас информировал
     о текущем местоположении.  Но вот
     сегодня столкнулся с устройством, где
     и это не работало, а все потому, что
     при создании MapView я использовал
     пустую строку в качестве ключа. Но
     сейчас создать ключ для старых версий
     карт невозможно.

Конечно можно вновь извартиться и использовать новые карты вместо старых, но есть пользователи, у которых нельзя использовать новые карты, а на местоположении завязана одна из основных фич приложения.

---

Так вот, каким способом определения местоположения пользуетесь Вы и как боретесь с проблемой, что находятся устройства, где это не работает?  Буду рад увидеть в качестве ответов примеры, как работает у вас

**UPD:** с этой [статьей](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) знаком, но собрав пример и запустив у себя удивился, насколько это батарее-прожорливо, сделал модификацию, но ничего не помогло
**UPD_2:** под неопределением местоположения я понимаю либо отсутствие такового, либо его неправильное нахождение, так как иногда приходили результаты 5 минутной давности, а с учетом движения это играет свою роль

**UPD_3:**  Всвязи с болишим числом просмотров вопроса, решил написать решение проблемы:  как  я нашел решение -  [описал в статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191290/)

Comment: создание отдельного map  в памяти - это конечно шедевр. Произведение индусской мысли.

В целом, есть много ситуаций, когда координаты могут не определяться. Например, телефон находиться в помещении.

Comment: Да я не сам в восторге, но когда ты тыкаешься несколько месяцев вслепую, не имея возможности дебага на девайсе, получая только ответ от людей, что местоположение не определилось, то уже не знаешь что и сделать.  
Однако почему, когда пользователь открывает любую карту, будь то стандартные карты гугла, яндекса,2гис или еще что-то, то местоположение определяется? В чем разница? Что бы Вы сделали?

Comment: Посмотрите [это](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc) видео. Там разработчики андроида рассказывают, как они мучаются, что бы получить хорошие координаты. Там есть и подсказки, как это все правильно использовать.

Comment: Спасибо за видео, но дело в том, что там они бъются над точностью, а мне надо хотя-бы получить :)

Answer (score 1):

> А каким способом вы определяете местоположение пользователя?

Проще всего попросить пользователя включить GPS.

Comment: я с вами не согласен.  
GPS дает самое медленное определение местоположение, а учитывая, что юзер действительно может находится в помещении, то это либо замедлит поиски, либо вообще не найдет.

Comment: Геолокация по IP не пойдет? Просто я так и не понял, для каких целей вам надо определять чье-то местоположение.

Comment: эм, вы писали программы под андроид? просто мне кажется, что вы не совсем понимаете о чем речь идет :) и нет, геолокация по IP не подойдет

Comment: Да, писал. Вы можете сказать, зачем вам нужно определять местоположение?

Comment: чтобы отсортировать определенные объекты по расстоянию до пользователя :)

Comment: Пишите альтернативный клиент для geocaching.com? Шутка. Решение зависит от размера объектов. Если это города -- то по IP, если рестораны и магазины -- без GPS не обойтись.

Comment: без gps можно обойтись, запустите на андроид любую карту без GPS, ваше местоположение определится с погрешностью в 50 метров, а если вы не в здании и того меньше

Comment: 50 метров? Я такого не видел. Обычно мое положение на карте в точке пересечения экватора с Гринвическим мередианом. Ладно, больше мне сказать нечего, удачи в ваших начинаниях!