# LocationListener: проблема в определении координат пользователя

Tags: геолокация, android, java

Здравствуйте!
Это следствие  [предыдущего моего вопроса.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243148/android-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Имеется вот такой вот [класс](http://pastebin.com/Y3Nw1QZT) для определения местоположения пользователя. По какой причине может не находиться на некоторых устройствах? Разрешения и прочая вещи есть, просто попадаются модели/прошивки, на которых случается неприятность.
Время ожидания, варьировалось различным образом и в приведенном коде выставлен не минимум.

ЗЫ: дал ссылку на код, так как массивно, а тут не очень приятно читать.

Comment: на 4.3 может не находиться по одной простой причине - пользователь может запретить конкретному приложению получать координаты.

Comment: надо будет запомнить

Comment: как показали эксперименты - callback просто не приходит.

Comment: а в 4.3 можно узнать, запретил ли пользователь данному приложению получать координаты?

Comment: даже не знаю, но думаю, это не приложения дело. Если пользователь решил, что gps не нужен приложению, то значит так и должно быть.
Единственное, что следует делать со стороны программы - это логировать сам факт, что координаты не удалось получить за какое-то время (например в течении 10-20 минут).

К примеру, я ещё как то могу понять, зачем Andgry Birds нужны мои координаты (они крутят рекламу), но к примеру словарику? Я понимаю, что им интересна статистика, но ведь не с точностью до +- метр?

Comment: Да, логирование наверное самое подходящее, то есть приложение бесплатное будет пытаться получить координаты, не получило координаты и перестало работать. Либо плати либо отдай координаты))))

Comment: >> бесплатно получить координаты

батарея далеко не бесплатна.

кстати, есть третий вариант - снос приложения. И кому будет лучше?

Comment: да с 4.3 это уже отдельный разговор, если запретил, то это проблемы юзера.
Меня волнует вопрос когда это можно сделать :)  
@KoVadim, а Вы запускил мой код или не проходят callback у LocationListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение своей  проблемы описал [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191290/)

Answer (score 0):

Проще на просторах тырнета найти нормальную реализацию... и -

1. да определить включен\выключен можно
2. корректно показывать пользователю окно настроек включения GPS а не тихо ждать чуда
3. не ставил бы жесткий таймаут, все работает в тасках - есть реализация где поочередно от самого приблизительного до более менее точного по всем провайдерам определяется местоположение. таймаут просто вырубит такую функциональность не дожидаясь ответа от того самого gps.
4. проблемы могут быть только на киндлах от амазона, в остальном правильная реализация будет работать на всех версиях почти одинаково.

Comment: хм, просто так о правильно реализации говорить можно часами, может покажете :) 
Вот не совсем, таймаут нужен для определенных целей.   
С другой стороны, без таймаута можно ждать бесконечно, так как ничего не находит. Для того он и был выставлен.

Comment: @andreich, не имею права выкладывать __собственную реализацию.)

возможно стоит глянуть на 
https://github.com/benjholla/Android-Applications/tree/master/Android%20Applications/OpenGPSTracker