# На эмуляторе определяет координаты местоположения, на реальном устройстве нет.В чем причина?

Tags: android, геолокация

```
 package com.paad.whereami;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class WhereAmI extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

LocationManager locationManager;
String svcName = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(svcName);

String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

updateWithNewLocation(l);
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
TextView myLocationText;
myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);

String latLongString = "No location found";
if (location != null) {
  double lat = location.getLatitude();
  double lng = location.getLongitude();
  latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
}

myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
                       latLongString);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

забудьте об этом способе определения геопозиции, он устарел и работает нестабильно. Google презентовал на Google IO 2013 новый способ, с помощью [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html). в документации есть небольшой [пример](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), как быстро прикрутить к своему проекту

Answer (score 1):

да, в одно время это была для меня очень острой проблемой.
[Вот, посмотрите это, пожалуйста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243575/locationlistener-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ссылка ведёт на другой вопрос этого же сайта - всё хорошо.

Comment: @Qwertiy редирект на SO в итоге, да. Не знал...

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/48576)

Comment: @Suvitruf вообще я дал ссылку, потому что ранее изучал этот вопрос и все что я нарыл, описал в вопросе по ссылке. Стоит изучить для начала, а потом предпринимать какие-то действия

Comment: @andreich или более развёрнутый ответ давать.

Comment: @Suvitruf ответ содержит достаточно информации, чтобы понять, что это ответ, а не вопрос :)

Comment: @andreich да, с этим согласен, причину по ошибке не ту выбрал. Но, согласитесь, не очень информативный ответ (: