# Определение местоположения под Android

Tags: геолокация, android, gps

Не могу заставить телефон получить координаты местоположения. Тестирую на реальном устройстве SG4.

Код

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private LocationManager myLocationManager;
private LocationListener myLocationListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    myLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    myLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name)," I listener you ");
            tv.setText("YEEES! I HERE!!!! I WORK!!! maybe ))");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    };

    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,myLocationListener);

}
```

В манифесте прописал разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

На телефоне GPS включил. Но событие onLocationChanged не срабатывает (((( ни в логах, ни на экране - без изменений. До туда просто не доходит дело.

Comment: а вы уверены, что телефон ловит нормально спутники?

Comment: Вроде да, я специально проверил через гугл-карты  - определил с точностью до метров 3х. Попробовал вместо GPS_PROVIDER поставить NETWORK_PROVIDER. Никакого эффекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотрите [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269925/android-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=269930#269930)

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас посмотрю. По своему коду могу сказать что заработал после того, как я включил гуглкарту (настройки не менял), и прошел по комнате. Теперь все выключил и моя программа нормально отображает координаты. Может что-то подвисло, не знаю даже ((. За ссылку спасибо еще раз, сейчас буду изучать.

Comment: как раз возникла проблема стабильности работы LocationManager. Google карты использовали свой велосипед на этот счет, до появления LocationClient, который перезапускал сервис для работы с геолокацией. Сервис этот в свою очередь имел особенность выгружаться из системы, если ей не хватало памяти, и не загружаться потом заного до перезагрузки самого девайса. в LocationClient эта проблема решена