# Проблема с получением координат gps в background для cordova приложения под Android

Tags: android, cordova, gps, meteor

Добрый день,

Пишу на Meteor JS  приложение под Android. Помимо всего прочего - приложение занимется трекингом местоположения пользователя по GPS. Используется плагин cordova-plugin-geolocation, который предоставляет доступ к объекту navigation.geolocation {highAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0, timeout: 3000}. Приложение большую часть времени свернуто, экран телефона выключен.

Проблема в том, что в городе трек еще "более-менее" c натяжкой, за городом - одни отскоки и  нормальные координаты прилетают "ОЧЕНЬ редко" - раз в 10 минут.

Поставил https://atmospherejs.com/mirrorcell/background-geolocation-plus - то же самое.

Однако, если параллельно на телефон поставить программу gps-трекер (мы ставили такой - https://github.com/Scoutgps/Scout-Tracker) -  то мое приложение  начинает выдавать отличный трек

Не могу понять в чем причина - может не хватает разрешений для доступа к точным координатам, получению обновлений в background-е

Не знаю куда копать

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за предложение.

В итоге, выяснил, что плагин cordova-geolocation-plugin использует старые способы получения координат на Android, завязанные на сервис LocationManager, который периодически подвисает.

Перешел на другой плагин и трек теперь идеальный (правда батарея улетает очень быстро)- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-locationservices  В его описании как раз и указано, что он пришел на заменy cordova-gelocation из-за  проблем в получении координат

Нашел суть решения проблемы в этом посте:

[Определение местоположения под Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274462/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что ваше приложение и Скаут, как-то по разному инициализируют работу устройства. Самое очевидное, что приходит в голову - различные вейклоки, чтобы устройство не засыпало и режимы поллинга GPS.

Есть 2 пути докопаться до истины:

1. Отламывать функциональность Скаута, пока он не начнет глючить ровно так, как и ваше приложение. Как только найдете - это и будет то самое, чего нехватало вашему приложению.
2. Смотреть исходники фреймверка (ну или дебугать по шагам) и смотреть, чем оно отличается от Скаута

Из астрала мне тут подсказывают, что у вас банальный режим экономии энергии, из-за которого и страдает точность.