# Подбор ближайшей точки по местоположению

Tags: android, java

Всем привет.

Делаю приложение под андроид. Помогите с вопросом, я уже гуглю фиг знает сколько.

Требуется по местоположению пользователя подобрать ближайшую точку (язык java) без gps. точки, например:
55.895859, 37.719324-точка 1
55.881231, 37.636800-точка 2
55.865430, 37.648020-точка 3

Объясните, пожалуйста, попонятнее, по действиям, я только начинаю втягиваться. )
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Имеется в виду, что вы хотите сравнить полученные координаты устройства с заранее известным набором координат неких точек и получить ближайшую?

Comment: Да, именно это и нужно. Поможете?

Comment: Можете написать, как это будет программно?.. Просто, на моем уровне программирования, боюсь, это часы гугленья...

Comment: @DenShDen, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Для вычисления расстояний между точками, заданными географическими координатами, на android можно воспользоваться методами *[Location.distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29)*, либо *[static Location.distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29)*.
Cравнение полученных расстояний не должно составить труда.

#### Пример

```
public class GeoPoint {

    public final double lat;

    public final double lon;

    public GeoPoint(double lat, double lon) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public GeoPoint(Location location) {
        this.lat = location.getLatitude();
        this.lon = location.getLongitude();
    }

    public static GeoPoint getNearestLocation(GeoPoint current, Collection<GeoPoint> locations) {
        GeoPoint res = null;
        float lastDisance = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        float locDistance[] = new float[1];
        for (GeoPoint loc: locations) {
            Location.distanceBetween(current.lat, current.lon,
                    loc.lat, loc.lon, locDistance);
            if (res == null || locDistance[0] < lastDisance) {
                res = loc;
                lastDisance = locDistance[0];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

##### Вызов

```
GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint(55.895859, 37.719324);
GeoPoint locations[] = new GeoPoint[] {
            new GeoPoint(55.895859, 37.719324),
            new GeoPoint(55.881231, 37.636800),
            new GeoPoint(55.865430, 37.648020)
    };

GeoPoint nearest = GeoPoint.getNearestLocation(currentLocation,
            Arrays.asList(locations));
```

Comment: а куда выводится?? ошибки не вылетает, но вывод то куда

Comment: @DenShDen, это пример. Вы сами можете переделать, как вам нужно, в т.ч. и добавить вывод

Answer (score 2):

Ну... Координаты прямоугольные. Вычисляйте дельту по X и Y, далее, по теореме Пифагора вычисляйте гипотенузу. Получете 3-и числа (по числу на точку. Если их три - значит три числа). Чем полученное число меньше, тем точка ближе.

**UPD:**

И вот внутренние ссылки на то, как это программно делать: [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269925#269930)

Comment: Можете написать, как это будет программно? Просто, на моем уровне программирования, боюсь, это часы гугленья...

Comment: @DenShDen, сам я в этом не разбираюсь. Перефразируйте вопрос (создав новый). Вам надо не "Подбор ближайшей точки по местоположению" узнать, а "Как получить текущие координаты устройста, Android".

Comment: Спасибо;) Сейчас перефразирую

Comment: Координаты не прямоугольные

Comment: @Алексей Илларионов, если исходить из определения с вики (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прямоугольная_система_координат), то я, вроде, не ошибся.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, географические координаты же, не на плоскости. Теорему Пифагора применить можно, но только если не важна точность. И формула на сфере другая.
[здесь](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#equirectangular), либо [на gis-lab на русском](http://gis-lab.info/qa/great-circles.html)

Comment: @Алексей Илларионов, да, вы правы. Просто в вопросе не были указаны единицы измерения)

Answer (score -4):

Если я правильно понял, надо узнать, к какой из трех точек мы ближе. Что там можно гуглить - непонятно. При чем тут уровень программирования, это задача на знание геометрии, пятый или шестой класс общеобразовательной школы. Берем и вычисляем расстояние от нас до каждой точки, выбираем ближайшую. Алгоритм прост, как три копейки, вот тебе готовая программа на C, чтобы хоть какой-то интеллект пришлось приложить, переводя код на эту вашу Java. Вообще, поражает математическая подготовка современных джавописателей....

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <math.h>   // hypot
#include <stdlib.h> // qsort

typedef struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double distance;
}
Point;

double Distance(Point* p1, Point* p2)
{
    return hypot(p1->x - p2->x, p1->y - p2->y);
}

int compare_distances(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    return (*(Point**)p1)->distance < (*(Point**)p2)->distance ? -1 : 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    Point point1 = { 55.895859, 37.719324 };
    Point point2 = { 55.881231, 37.636800 };
    Point point3 = { 55.865430, 37.648020 };
    Point* points[3] = { &point1, &point2, &point3 };
    Point me;
    do
    {
        scanf("%lf %lf", &(me.x), &(me.y));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            points[i]->distance = Distance(points[i], &me);
        }
        qsort(points, 3, sizeof(Point*), compare_distances);
        printf("%f %f\n", points[0]->x, points[0]->y);
    }
    while (me.x != 0.0 || me.y != 0.0);
    return 0;
}
```