# Как определить текущие местоположение?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, java

Как можно узнать мои координаты без карт? Вот так я получаю мои координаты с картой.

```
myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
// Getting Current Location
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if (location != null) {
   double latitude = location.getLatitude();
   double longitude = location.getLongitude();
   myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);}
```

Как можно получить мое местоположение не создавая обьект myMap (GoogleMap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вам стоило погуглить немного. Раз не вышло, вот вам ссылочка на мои мучения: [LocationListener: проблема в определении координат пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243575/java-locationlistener-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F).

Comment: Разленились студенты в край) Спасибо)